# Issues when copying data to my NTFS external Terabyte Harddrive - Natty 32bit

Tags: 11.04, ntfs, kernel

I'm having issues every time I copy a large sum of files to my External harddrive from my actual harddrive - what happens is that it gets at a certain point in the copying stage then it freezes and my caps lock button blinks.

I took a video to show exactly what happened: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsLxmyz5hQ0

If the video isnt showing up right away, its still processing.

Comment: Sounds like you've had a kernel panic.

Comment: @Alex - have you done a chkdsk (via windows) on the external drive?

Comment: Seen some other Linux posts that this maybe related to your wireless card driver. What type of wireless card is n this system?

Answer (score 1):

Thats a odd issue it really sounds like that part of your tb drive is bad/corrupt.

- As fossfreadom had said you may try running chkdsk from windows on that drive .
- It may be one video it gets hung on try to move 1 movie at a time .
- Check to see if you have the most current bios for your computer.

I hope that 1 of the 3 will help you